# Symfony2 - FOS UserBundle Sonata Admin/UserBundle error when selecting on on 'enable' user in dashboard

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I've managed to get the FOS UserBundle working with Sonata Admin/UserBundle with this guide here:

[Integrate FOSUserBundle and SonataUserBundle Easily](http://m2mdas.github.io/blog/2013/11/18/integrate-fosuserbundle-and-sonatauserbundle-easily/)

Yet when I click on 'enable' or 'lock' any option in the dashboard, I get this html/log code instead of the user being enabled, disabled, locked, unlocked etc.

**How can I fix this?**

Code for config.yml is below --- See below and screen shot:
[image: error when clicking enable to true]

**config.yml**

```
    # FOS UserBundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Test\UserBundle\Entity\User
#    user_class: Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser

    group:
            group_class:   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
            group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager    # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager for mongodb)

    service:
            user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager    # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.group_manager for mongodb)

#    doctrine:
#
#        dbal:
#            types:
#                json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

# Sonata AdminBundle
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

# Sonata UserBundle
sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb

sonata_block:
    blocks:
        #...
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text: # used to if you plan to use Sonata user routes

parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.user.entity: Test\UserBundle\Entity\User
    sonata.user.admin.user.class: Test\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin

services:
    sonata.user.admin.group:
        abstract: true
        public: false
```

**error code**

```
</li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">finishRequest</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$request</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$type</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li></ol>
</div>
</li>
<li>
at
<strong>
<abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel">HttpKernel</abbr>
-&gt;handle
</strong>
(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request">Request</abbr>), '1', <em>true</em>)

<br />
in <abbr title="/var/www/html/test/app/">kernel.root_dir</abbr>/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3058&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('trace-0-8'); switchIcons('icon-0-8-open', 'icon-0-8-close'); return false;"><img class="toggle" id="icon-0-8-close" alt="-" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQSANft94TG57Hb8GS44ez1+mC24IvK6ePx+Wa44dXs92+942e54o3L6W2844/M6dnu+P/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABIALAAAAAASABIAQAVCoCQBTBOd6Kk4gJhGBCTPxysJb44K0qD/ER/wlxjmisZkMqBEBW5NHrMZmVKvv9hMVsO+hE0EoNAstEYGxG9heIhCADs=" style="display: none" /><img class="toggle" id="icon-0-8-open" alt="+" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQTANft99/v+Ga44bHb8ITG52S44dXs9+z1+uPx+YvK6WC24G+944/M6W28443L6dnu+Ge54v/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABMALAAAAAASABIAQAVS4DQBTiOd6LkwgJgeUSzHSDoNaZ4PU6FLgYBA5/vFID/DbylRGiNIZu74I0h1hNsVxbNuUV4d9SsZM2EzWe1qThVzwWFOAFCQFa1RQq6DJB4iIQA7" style="display: inline" /></a> <div id="trace-0-8" style="display: none" class="trace">
<ol start="3055"><li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">container</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">enterScope</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'request'</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">container</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">set</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'request'</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$request</span><span style="color: #007700">,</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'request'</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code>try&nbsp;{</code></li>
<li class="selected"><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$response&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">parent</span><span style="color: #007700">::</span><span style="color: #0000BB">handle</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$request</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$type</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$catch</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code>}&nbsp;catch&nbsp;(\<span style="color: #0000BB">Exception&nbsp;$e</span><span style="color: #007700">)&nbsp;{</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">container</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">set</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'request'</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">null</span><span style="color: #007700">,</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'request'</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">container</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">leaveScope</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'request'</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li></ol>
</div>
</li>
<li>
at
<strong>
<abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel">ContainerAwareHttpKernel</abbr>
-&gt;handle
</strong>
(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request">Request</abbr>), '1', <em>true</em>)

<br />
in <abbr title="/var/www/html/test/app/">kernel.root_dir</abbr>/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2308&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('trace-0-9'); switchIcons('icon-0-9-open', 'icon-0-9-close'); return false;"><img class="toggle" id="icon-0-9-close" alt="-" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQSANft94TG57Hb8GS44ez1+mC24IvK6ePx+Wa44dXs92+942e54o3L6W2844/M6dnu+P/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABIALAAAAAASABIAQAVCoCQBTBOd6Kk4gJhGBCTPxysJb44K0qD/ER/wlxjmisZkMqBEBW5NHrMZmVKvv9hMVsO+hE0EoNAstEYGxG9heIhCADs=" style="display: none" /><img class="toggle" id="icon-0-9-open" alt="+" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQTANft99/v+Ga44bHb8ITG52S44dXs9+z1+uPx+YvK6WC24G+944/M6W28443L6dnu+Ge54v/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABMALAAAAAASABIAQAVS4DQBTiOd6LkwgJgeUSzHSDoNaZ4PU6FLgYBA5/vFID/DbylRGiNIZu74I0h1hNsVxbNuUV4d9SsZM2EzWe1qThVzwWFOAFCQFa1RQq6DJB4iIQA7" style="display: inline" /></a> <div id="trace-0-9" style="display: none" class="trace">
<ol start="2305"><li><code>if&nbsp;(<span style="color: #0000BB">false&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">===&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">booted</span><span style="color: #007700">)&nbsp;{</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">boot</span><span style="color: #007700">();</span></code></li>
<li><code>}</code></li>
<li class="selected"><code>return&nbsp;<span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">getHttpKernel</span><span style="color: #007700">()-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">handle</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$request</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$type</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$catch</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code>}</code></li>
<li><code>protected&nbsp;function&nbsp;<span style="color: #0000BB">getHttpKernel</span><span style="color: #007700">()</span></code></li>
<li><code>{</code></li></ol>
</div>
</li>
<li>
at
<strong>
<abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>
-&gt;handle
</strong>
(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request">Request</abbr>))

<br />
in /var/www/html/test/web/app_dev.php at line 28&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('trace-0-10'); switchIcons('icon-0-10-open', 'icon-0-10-close'); return false;"><img class="toggle" id="icon-0-10-close" alt="-" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQSANft94TG57Hb8GS44ez1+mC24IvK6ePx+Wa44dXs92+942e54o3L6W2844/M6dnu+P/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABIALAAAAAASABIAQAVCoCQBTBOd6Kk4gJhGBCTPxysJb44K0qD/ER/wlxjmisZkMqBEBW5NHrMZmVKvv9hMVsO+hE0EoNAstEYGxG9heIhCADs=" style="display: none" /><img class="toggle" id="icon-0-10-open" alt="+" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQTANft99/v+Ga44bHb8ITG52S44dXs9+z1+uPx+YvK6WC24G+944/M6W28443L6dnu+Ge54v/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABMALAAAAAASABIAQAVS4DQBTiOd6LkwgJgeUSzHSDoNaZ4PU6FLgYBA5/vFID/DbylRGiNIZu74I0h1hNsVxbNuUV4d9SsZM2EzWe1qThVzwWFOAFCQFa1RQq6DJB4iIQA7" style="display: inline" /></a> <div id="trace-0-10" style="display: none" class="trace">
<ol start="25"><li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$kernel&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;new&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">AppKernel</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'dev'</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">true</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$kernel</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">loadClassCache</span><span style="color: #007700">();</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$request&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">Request</span><span style="color: #007700">::</span><span style="color: #0000BB">createFromGlobals</span><span style="color: #007700">();</span></code></li>
<li class="selected"><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$response&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$kernel</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">handle</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$request</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$response</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">send</span><span style="color: #007700">();</span></code></li>
<li><code><span style="color: #0000BB">$kernel</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">terminate</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$request</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$response</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></code></li>
<li><code>
</code></li></ol>
</div>
</li>
</ol>
</div>

<div class="block">
<div class="logs clear-fix">
<h2>
Logs&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('logs'); switchIcons('icon-logs-open', 'icon-logs-close'); return false;"><img class="toggle" id="icon-logs-open" alt="+" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQTANft99/v+Ga44bHb8ITG52S44dXs9+z1+uPx+YvK6WC24G+944/M6W28443L6dnu+Ge54v/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABMALAAAAAASABIAQAVS4DQBTiOd6LkwgJgeUSzHSDoNaZ4PU6FLgYBA5/vFID/DbylRGiNIZu74I0h1hNsVxbNuUV4d9SsZM2EzWe1qThVzwWFOAFCQFa1RQq6DJB4iIQA7" style="display: none" /><img class="toggle" id="icon-logs-close" alt="-" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQSANft94TG57Hb8GS44ez1+mC24IvK6ePx+Wa44dXs92+942e54o3L6W2844/M6dnu+P/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABIALAAAAAASABIAQAVCoCQBTBOd6Kk4gJhGBCTPxysJb44K0qD/ER/wlxjmisZkMqBEBW5NHrMZmVKvv9hMVsO+hE0EoNAstEYGxG9heIhCADs=" style="display: inline" /></a></h2>
<div class="error-count">
<span>
1 error
</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="logs">
<ol class="traces logs">
<li>
INFO - Matched route &quot;sonata_admin_set_object_field_value&quot; (parameters: &quot;_controller&quot;: &quot;sonata.admin.controller.admin:setObjectFieldValueAction&quot;, &quot;_route&quot;: &quot;sonata_admin_set_object_field_value&quot;)
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Read SecurityContext from the session
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Reloading user from user provider.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Username &quot;admintest&quot; was reloaded from user provider.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
</li>
<li class="error">
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: &quot;Notice: Undefined index: enabled in /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php line 390&quot; at /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php line 390
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.request&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
<li>
DEBUG - Notified event &quot;kernel.controller&quot; to listener &quot;Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController&quot;.
</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>


<div class="block">
<h2>
Stack Trace (Plain Text)&nbsp;
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('traces-text'); switchIcons('icon-traces-text-open', 'icon-traces-text-close'); return false;"><img class="toggle" id="icon-traces-text-close" alt="-" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQSANft94TG57Hb8GS44ez1+mC24IvK6ePx+Wa44dXs92+942e54o3L6W2844/M6dnu+P/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABIALAAAAAASABIAQAVCoCQBTBOd6Kk4gJhGBCTPxysJb44K0qD/ER/wlxjmisZkMqBEBW5NHrMZmVKvv9hMVsO+hE0EoNAstEYGxG9heIhCADs=" style="display: none" /><img class="toggle" id="icon-traces-text-open" alt="+" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQTANft99/v+Ga44bHb8ITG52S44dXs9+z1+uPx+YvK6WC24G+944/M6W28443L6dnu+Ge54v/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABMALAAAAAASABIAQAVS4DQBTiOd6LkwgJgeUSzHSDoNaZ4PU6FLgYBA5/vFID/DbylRGiNIZu74I0h1hNsVxbNuUV4d9SsZM2EzWe1qThVzwWFOAFCQFa1RQq6DJB4iIQA7" style="display: inline" /></a> </h2>

<div id="traces-text" class="trace" style="display: none;">
<pre>[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: enabled in /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php line 390
at n/a
in /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php line 390

at Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'Undefined index: enabled', '/var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php', '390', array('property' => 'enabled'))
in /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php line 390

at Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata->getPropertyMetadata('enabled')
in /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 171

at Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateProperty(object(User), 'enabled', null)
in /var/www/html/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php line 116

at Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator->validateProperty(object(User), 'enabled')
in /var/www/html/test/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Controller/HelperController.php line 273

at Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\HelperController->setObjectFieldValueAction(object(Request))
in line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(HelperController), 'setObjectFieldValueAction'), array(object(Request)))
in /var/www/html/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2947

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
in /var/www/html/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2909

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
in /var/www/html/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3058

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
in /var/www/html/test/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2308

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in /var/www/html/test/web/app_dev.php line 28

</pre>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function toggle(id, clazz) {
var el = document.getElementById(id),
current = el.style.display,
i;

if (clazz) {
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (i = tags.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
if (tags[i].className === clazz) {
tags[i].style.display = 'none';
}
}
}

el.style.display = current === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}

function switchIcons(id1, id2) {
var icon1, icon2, display1, display2;

icon1 = document.getElementById(id1);
icon2 = document.getElementById(id2);

display1 = icon1.style.display;
display2 = icon2.style.display;

icon1.style.display = display2;
icon2.style.display = display1;
}
//]]></script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: No, have you run into the same issue?

Comment: yes, but this bug is only in dev env so not big deal. I see you raised a bug so it may be solved one day ;)

Comment: i m getting the same issue any help??